# Why does my pandas code raise assignment warnings and run slowly?

Tags: python, pandas, loops, dataframe, warnings

I am doing a project where I have to handle with a lot of diagnoses. No matter what the purpose is, in terms of coding, I think that the code below is right, however it takes to much time (~1h) and it always shows me warnings. Is there anything that I am not doing right? Thank you in advance

```
# The first 3 values are the only that matters
diagnoses_sec = df[['Diagnóstico 2', 'Diagnóstico 3', 'Diagnóstico 4', 'Diagnóstico 5', 'Diagnóstico 6',
          'Diagnóstico 7', 'Diagnóstico 8', 'Diagnóstico 9', 'Diagnóstico 10', 'Diagnóstico 11', 'Diagnóstico 12', 
          'Diagnóstico 13', 'Diagnóstico 14', 'Diagnóstico 15', 'Diagnóstico 16', 'Diagnóstico 17', 'Diagnóstico 18', 
          'Diagnóstico 19', 'Diagnóstico 20']]
for i in range(0, diagnoses_sec.shape[1]):
    diagnoses_sec.iloc[:,i].fillna("ZZZ", inplace = True)
    diagnoses_sec.iloc[:,i] = diagnoses_sec.iloc[:,i].str.slice(start=0, stop=3, step=1)
```

In this part, there is a warning, but I can't understand why:

```
C:\Users\Asus\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py:630: SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead

See the caveats in the documentation: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy
  self.obj[item_labels[indexer[info_axis]]] = value
```

The second part of the code is that:

```
from bisect import bisect_left

diag_icd10_ranges = ["B99","D49","D89","E89","F99","G99","H59","H95",
          "I99","J99","K95", "L99", "M99", "N99","O9A","P96","Q99",
          "R99","T88","Y99","Z99","ZZZ"]

diag_icd10_dict = {0: 'infectious_icd10d', 1: 'neoplasms_icd10d', 2: 'blood_icd10d', 3: 'endocrine_icd10d',
                   4: 'mental_icd10d', 5: 'nervous_icd10d', 6: 'eye_icd10d', 7: 'ear_icd10d',
                   8: 'circulatory_icd10d', 9: 'respiratory_icd10d', 10: 'digestive_icd10d', 11: 'skin_icd10d', 
                  12: 'musculo_icd10d', 13: 'genitourinary_icd10d', 14: 'pregnancy_icd10d', 15: 'perinatalperiod_icd10d', 
                  16: 'congenital_icd10d',
                  17: 'abnormalfindings_icd10d', 18:'injury_icd10d', 19:'morbidity', 20:'healthstatus', 21:'Nan_Category'}

# function to categorize every patient
def icdGroup(code): return bisect_left(diag_icd10_ranges,code)

# loop for the categorisation of every patient in every diagnose
for i_diag_sec in range(0,diagnoses_sec.shape[1]):
    for i_within_diag_sec in range(0, len(diagnoses_sec)):
        diagnoses_sec.iloc[i_within_diag_sec,i_diag_sec] = icdGroup(diagnoses_sec.iloc[i_within_diag_sec,i_diag_sec])
```

And once again I have another warning:

```
C:\Users\Asus\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\ipykernel_launcher.py:20: SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame

See the caveats in the documentation: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting these `SettingWithCopyWarning` warning messages as `diagnoses_sec` is a copy of part of `df`; setting values on this copy raises a warning to make sure that you are aware of this - your changes will not propagate back to `df`. These warnings will disappear if you explicitly make a copy using the [`copy`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.copy.html) method, e.g.:

```
diagnoses_sec = df[['Diagnóstico 2', 'Diagnóstico 3']].copy()
```

Regarding the time taken to execute your code, iterating over pandas `DataFrame`s in this way is inefficient and you should strive to use vectorized operations, applying a function or operation to an entire array.

You could modify your first example to do this:

```
diagnoses_sec = df[['Diagnóstico 2', 'Diagnóstico 3', 'Diagnóstico 4', 'Diagnóstico 5', 'Diagnóstico 6',
          'Diagnóstico 7', 'Diagnóstico 8', 'Diagnóstico 9', 'Diagnóstico 10', 'Diagnóstico 11', 'Diagnóstico 12', 
          'Diagnóstico 13', 'Diagnóstico 14', 'Diagnóstico 15', 'Diagnóstico 16', 'Diagnóstico 17', 'Diagnóstico 18', 
          'Diagnóstico 19', 'Diagnóstico 20']].copy()
diagnoses_sec.fillna("ZZZ", inplace=True)
diagnoses_sec = diagnoses_sec.apply(lambda x: x.str.slice(start=0, stop=3, step=1))
```

Here, `fillna` is applied to the entire `DataFrame` and will replace every `NA` value with `"ZZZ"`. In the second operation, [`apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) will, via a `lambda` function, perform the string slicing operation on each column (`Series`) of your `diagnoses_sec` `DataFrame`.

Your second case is similar, though since your `icdGroup` function is not vectorized (it doesn't operate on a `DataFrame` or `Series`) and is being applied to every cell of your `DataFrame`, you can use [`applymap`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.applymap.html) to execute it on every value:

```
diagnoses_sec = diagnoses_sec.applymap(icdGroup)
```

Comment: Thank you so so much @dspencer! You have no idea how much you have helped me! I didn't know about that!